# HTTP servlet with Tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, servlets

I'm starting to learn servlet and I'm using MySQL and Tomcat. I'm trying to make a simple servlet that when the submit button is clicked it will display a different set of instruction by calling the `doGet()` function again and moves the cursor to the next set.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
{         
    out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Instructions</TITLE><HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT InstructNo, Instruct FROM Intructions");

    if(rs.next())
    {
        out.println(rs.getString("InstructNo") + ". " + rs.getString("Instruct"));
    }

    out.println("<form method=\"get\" action=\"\">");
    out.println("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"ans\" value=\"true\">True<br>");
    out.println("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"ans\" value=\"true\">False<br>");
    out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">");
    out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
```

I can't figure out how to move the cursor to the next set when submit button is clicked and 
call the `doGet()` function gets called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need store something that lets you know where you are in the list. So, for example, add a hidden form field with some sort of value that lets you read the right thing from your database. I'll assume your records in the db are numbered.

```
  out.println("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"ans\" value=\"true\">False<br>");
  out.println("<input type='hidden' name='index' value='" + index + "' />");
  out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">");
```

Then you need to collect the that value when the server gets the request and use it to read the next value:

```
 String index = req.getParameter("index");
 int idx = Integer.parseInt(index); // add code to detect an exception here
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT InstructNo, Instruct FROM Intructions where Index=" + index); // Check my rusty SQL here
```

Then figure out the next one:

```
index = "" + (idx+1); // The +1 means to get the next one next time
out.println("<form method=\"get\" action=\"\">");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing the `if` statement with a while loop for iterating over all the records in the database and then you can use the same code to print it to the web page.

You may also want to learn about using JSPs which makes the separation between the controller (the servlet) and the view (the web page presented to the user; or the JSP).